# Can you identify this helicopter?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

I saw this helicopter in Hungary. It might be an [Airbus H225M](https://www.airbus.com/helicopters/military-helicopters/heavy/h225m.html), but I'm not sure. Can you confirm or identify it correctly?

[image: Unknown helicopter seen in Hungary]

<sup>Unknown helicopter seen in Hungary</sup>

What is the red spot on the side, under the tail boom?

Comment: Wow, you went through the trouble of panning along with one of the rotor blades, so it would be sharp whilst the helicopter is motion-blurred! Interesting as this demonstrates that the tail rotor turns counterclockwise/backwards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the [Airbus Helicopters H225](https://www.airbus.com/helicopters/civil-helicopters/heavy/h225/h225-missions.html) (previously Eurocopter EC225 Super Puma). What most notably differentiates this version from the earlier [H215](https://www.airbus.com/helicopters/civil-helicopters/heavy/h215.html), are the rotor assemblies: H225 has a five blade main rotor and four blade tail rotor, H215 the blade counts are "opposite", being four for the main rotor and five for the tail rotor. Otherwise, the models are externally quite similar.

As for the red object on the side: thanks for Affe for pointing me in the right direction, the device is an *Emergency Helicopter Locator*. Below is a picture taken from [Heli-One mods catalogue 2018](https://www.heli-one.com%20%E2%80%BA%20h...PDF%20Mods%20catalogue%202018%20-%20Heli-One), page 67, which shows the device installed on Sikorsky S-76 A/C.
[image: Emergency Helicopter Locator]
The brochure describes the device as follows:

> The system features
> a locator beacon containing the transmitter and antenna. This is automatically
> activated and released in the event of a crash,
> or activation of the water sensor, or manual deployment by the flight crew. The
> beacon transmits on all international distress frequencies and is compatible with the
> COSPAS/SARSAT system. Its GPS input will allow the beacon to transmit the last
> known position of the aircraft in distress, saving lives.

Comment: jpe61 thanks for yor answer, but what is red point on side?

Comment: Let me verify my thoughts, I'll get back at ya.

Comment: This is a tricky one, on H225 it's on the side of a fuel tank, but I'm unable to verify that the doohickey is (or is not) fuel related. Some H225's have it, some don't. It's not specifically civilian or military stuff either.

Comment: It's a cpi/emergency locator beacon.

Answer (score 2):

That’s an Airbus Helicopters H225 Super Puma.

Comment: I think that should be either *Airbus Helicopters H215*, or the old designation *Eurocopter AS332 Super Puma*.

Comment: Good catch! Fixed it.